# Back to same view after Ajax request and Spring response

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, spring

I tray save data to server and to refresh view with added data.  After sending multipart request to server. On server part it possible to save data to base and back json object. Problem is,  not possible to refresh same view, server send json response by action method. I can redirect  but this no option. No error arise.  I find simile post it was  appeal to use  e.preventDefault() in trigger  click() function and Ajax option override:true,  but this not help. How bypath it?

```
Template code .  

        <form  action="/video/addCasePost" id="formAddPoster" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

                    <div class="form-group">    
                  <label for="caseTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label">title</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="caseTitle" name="caseTitle" value="" placeholder=“add” title here …  />
                </div>
                  </div>
<div class="form-group">

                    <label for="casePosterLoad" class="col-sm-2 control-label">post</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10  ">
                           <input type="file" name="file" required id="fileLoader" /> 
                    </div>
                      </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-sm" id="postId" name="postId" value="{{item.postId}}" />
                        <button type="submit" id="btnSaveCasePost" class="btn btn-default"></button>  
                      <!-- save content --> 
                    </div>
                  </div> 



function casePostUpload()
    {
var myForm = form.find('formAddPoster');
    myData = new FormData();
    myData.append('multipart',  myForm);

       $
          .ajax({

              url : "/video/addCasePost",
              data : myForm,
              type : 'POST',
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
              enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
              processData: false, 
              contentType:false,
              success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){


                  $('#casePost').prepend('<br/>Poster: '+data.casePoster+' ::  title '+data.caseTitle+' at '+data.timestampAsStr+'<br/></td></tr>');


            },
              error : function(result){
                  //...;

                alert('add contnt error: ' + errorThrown);
              }
          });
    }






Spring MVC controller method


    @RequestMapping(value = "/video/addCasePost",   method = RequestMethod.POST )
 public @ResponseBody CasePost addcasepost( @RequestPart("caseTitle") String caseTitleString, 
    @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @ModelAttribute("currentuser") User currentuser) throws Exception {
   CasePost jsResponse = new CasePost();


    String filePath = new String();
     //save file to directory 
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            String uploadsDir = “/fd/ct/images/";
            String realPathtoUploads =  request.getServletContext().getRealPath(uploadsDir);
            if(! new File(realPathtoUploads).exists())
              {
                new File(realPathtoUploads).mkdir();
              }


            String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
             filePath = realPathtoUploads + orgName;

            File dest = new File(filePath);
            file.transferTo(dest);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e);
            }

    }   

    try {
        if (caseTitleString != null) {



            jsResponse.setCaseTitle(caseTitleString);

            jsResponse.setCasePoster(filePath);

            jsResponse = graphStoryInterface.getCasePostInterface().add(jsResponse, currentuser);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }

 return jsResponse;


}
```

Comment: by "refresh view", do you mean adding some HTML to an existing element?  your ajax call shows you adding something to the `#casePost` element, but that doesn't seem to exist in your HTML code.

Comment: you either use form action or you use ajax alone. Since you are using ajax, you may get rid of formAction and then process the data on response. No need to reload/redirect.

Comment: Winter Soldier  For send request  only ajax was used.

Comment: dhc  This  HTML  code to exist  but I don't add in the post. I think it not relevant with this case.

Answer (score 0):

The [form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) is not being passed in your case.

Modified the forma dat a& trimmed the formAction as its not required.

```
function casePostUpload() {
 myData = new FormData($('#formAddPoster'));
 myData.append('multipart',  myForm);
 $.ajax({
      url : "/video/addCasePost",
      data : myData,
      type : 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      processData: false, 
      contentType:false,
      success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
          $('#casePost').prepend('<br/>Poster: '+data.casePoster+' ::  title '+data.caseTitle+' at '+data.timestampAsStr+'<br/></td></tr>');
    },
      error : function(result){
          //...;

        alert('add contnt error: ' + errorThrown);
      }
  });
}

<form id="formAddPoster" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="caseTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label">title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="caseTitle" name="caseTitle" value="" placeholder=“add” title here … />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="casePosterLoad" class="col-sm-2 control-label">post</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10  ">
      <input type="file" name="file" required id="fileLoader" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control input-sm" id="postId" name="postId" value="{{item.postId}}" />
      <button type="submit" id="btnSaveCasePost" class="btn btn-default"></button>
      <!-- save content -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: With FormData object all ok. Firebag show 200 ok. Content-Type multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------158gsd546464546564. I can sand file  and json.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved or where are you stuck at this moment?

Comment: Some point  before  posting it . response back to url by Ajax method /video/addCasePost

Comment: I was able path over this stack. Problem was with Jquery version. Old version not recognize some method. Thx Winter Soldier your  answer pull some ideas.)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Could you please accept the answer if it's resolved so others needn't spent time on this. Thanks

Comment: I tray but I don't have this privilege (